# OCaml conversion int into num

Tags: numbers, ocaml

I have an issue with `num` numbers.
I want to to attribute

```
   let one = num_of_int 1
   let zero = num_of_int 0
```

so I open `num` library

```
   open Num
```

and got error when I want to implement this.

```
# open Num
# let one = num_of_int 1
# let zero = num_of_int 0;;
File "", line 2, characters 21-22:
Error: This expression has type Num.num
   but an expression was expected of type int
```

Please correct it if you can and give me some link where can I learn how to solve this kind of problems in the future.

Thanks for helping.

#### Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you described is not one of the official OCaml. All the recent versions of official OCaml accepts your code in the question.

```
$ ocaml nums.cma
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# open Num
  let one = num_of_int 1
  let zero = num_of_int 0;;
val one : num = Int 1
val zero : num = Int 0
#
```

I guess you are using a variant, possibly TryOCaml. I guess it has a nice (but unfortunately confusing this time) way of parsing integer literals.

Answer (score 1):

In the most recent OCaml, it appears that if you open the Num module, then `1` is interpreted as Num already. You don't need to convert it. This seems like magic to me, but I have observed it in practice at [try.ocamlpro.com](http://try.ocamlpro.com).

```
    Welcome to TryOCaml (v. 4.01.0)

# open Num;;
# 1;;
- : Num.num = Num 1
```

Usually I wouldn't open the Num module. There are many conflicts with pervasives. Maybe a local open:

```
let open Num in <expr>
```

Comment: It is not the behaviour of OCaml 4.01.0. TryOCaml seems not to be the vanilla OCaml 4.01.0.

Comment: Thanks, very good to know! Strange that czarnywdowiec is seeing something so similar.

Comment: I guess he is another user of TryOCaml :-)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that, but I need it to change to use in the rest part of program. To calculate big numbers with +- 100 digits I need to have only 'num'

```
   open Num


   let one = num_of_int 1
   let zero = num_of_int 0

   let rec silnia n = 
   if n < 2 
   then one
   else (num_of_int n) */ silnia(n-1) 

   let rec newton n k =
   silnia n // (silnia k */ silnia (n-k))

   let bell = Array.make 101 zero;;
   bell.(0) <- one;; 
   bell.(1) <- one;;


   let i = ref 2
   let k = ref 0
   let x = ref zero
   let suma = ref zero

   let n = ref 100


 if !n != 0 || !n != 1 then
   while !i <= !n do   
        while !k <= (!i-1) do
          x := newton (!i-1) !k;
          suma := !suma +/ (!x */ bell.(!k));
          k := !k + 1 
        done;
      bell.(!k) <- (!suma);   
      suma:= zero;
      k:=0;
      i:= !i + 1;
   done;;
```